# How to lazy load individual components of the same page in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading

Loading all components or widgets in the page altogether slows down the rendering time of the application.

I want `app-sidebar1`, `app-body`, `app-sidebar2` to load on to the DOM based on priority one after another and not wait to download all components at once and show the screen. (The space used by the components may be blank till the component itself loads.

Template file looks like:

```
<div>
...
<app-sidebar1></app-sidebar1>
<app-body></app-body>
<app-sidebar2></app-sidebar2>
...
</div>
```

Module File looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SecondaryMenuComponent,
    NoHeaderFooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'serverApp'}),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FlexModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    ExtendedModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LoginModule,
    LogoutModule,

    app-sidebar1,
    app-body,
    app-sidebar2

  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'baseURL', useValue: baseURL,
    },
    SidenavCommunicationService,
    // {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    UserService,
    AuthGuard,
    PaymentValidityGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How do I prioritize download of specific components based on their urgency?

Comment: what have you done so far? You have to show your code or post code snippets. No one can tell you how to code, if you post a stackblitz link or your attempt that way we can help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

But for your answer, general answer is to make a module like ABC module, then have child 1 and child 2 components inside the ABC module. If Child 1 and Child 2 are in itself bigger ones, you can make them feature modules. So then Child 1 is a module and it will have its own sub child 1 component etc.. So that is how the concept works generally. 
Divide into modules.